# How to rotate a canvas circle continuously?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

https://codepen.io/saketkr7/pen/KKmzXOV
I have a circle canvas in which n items are placed, I want to rotate all items placed? How can I do that?

[![`

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var items  = ['a', 'b' , 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g'];
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var n = 6;
var numElements = 8;
 var angle = 0;
 var step = (2*Math.PI) / numElements;
var rotateAngle = 36 * Math.PI / 180; 
for(var i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
    var x = 500/2 + 100 * Math.cos(angle);
    var y = 500/2 + 100 * Math.sin(angle);
     console.log(x, y);    
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
     ctx.stroke();
     angle += step;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.
</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/robTi.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/robTi.png)

Answer (score 1):

### requestAnimationFrame

Use [requestAnimationFrame(callback)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) (rAF) to render the animation.

The callback function is responsible for rendering each animation frame. In this case it will clear the canvas and draw the circles.

The callback function gets the time in milliseconds (1/1000th seconds). You can use that to set the rotation angle. The first example uses the `time` and the constant `rate` to define the number of rotations per second.

In the callback function you need to request the new frame by calling rAF.

To start the animation request the first frame.

### Rendering

Modify your code so that it is a function that can be called for each frame of the animation. In the example your modified code is in the function `drawCircles(angle)` where angle is the current rotation in radians.

Pass it an argument that is the current rotation.

### Example

The snippet below does what is described above.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const rate = 0.2; // Number of rotations per second

function drawCircles(angle) {
    var i = 0;
    const numElements = 8;
    const step = (2 * Math.PI) / numElements;
    ctx.beginPath();
    while (i < numElements) {
         const x = ctx.canvas.width / 2 + 100 * Math.cos(angle + i * step);
         const y = ctx.canvas.height / 2 + 100 * Math.sin(angle + i * step);
         ctx.moveTo(x + 10, y);
         ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
         i++;
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}


requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);  // rAF to start animation

function renderLoop(time) {  // rAF callback
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    drawCircles(((time * Math.PI * 2) / 1000) * rate);

    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);  // request next frame
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "canvas" width="220" height="220"></canvas>
```

On many devices the frame rate will be very stable, you can use a fixed rate time to get a smoother animation. As shown in next snippet. Be aware that time will drift if device drops frames.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const rate = 0.2; // APPROX Number of rotations per second
var frame = 0;    // counts frames

function drawCircles(angle) {
    var i = 0;
    const numElements = 8;
    const step = (2 * Math.PI) / numElements;
    ctx.beginPath();
    while (i < numElements) {
         const x = ctx.canvas.width / 2 + 100 * Math.cos(angle + i * step);
         const y = ctx.canvas.height / 2 + 100 * Math.sin(angle + i * step);
         ctx.moveTo(x + 10, y);
         ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
         i++;
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}


requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);  // rAF to start animation

function renderLoop() {  // rAF callback
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    time = frame++ * (1000 / 60);   // Assumes 60 fps
    drawCircles(((time * Math.PI * 2) / 1000) * rate);

    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);  // request next frame
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "canvas" width="220" height="220"></canvas>
```

### Update

Re comments

The @MDN.API.CanvasRenderingContext2D@ is not best for 3D. The best option is to use WebGL However there is a steep learning curve for WebGL.

3D can be done on the 2D API but you need to implement all the 3D rendering code in JS which will be orders of magnitude slower than WebGl.

### 3D via 2D API

The example below uses the 2D canvas to render a rotating ring of toon-shaded spheres rotating in 3D.

It is the most basic example and will not support cameras, lights, textures, etc..

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const rate = 0.2; // APPROX Number of rotations per second
const numCircles = 18;
const perspectiveRange = 300;  // dist between front and back planes
const ringRadius = 60;         // in pixels
const circleRadius = 10;       // in pixels. Radius of circle at z === 0
const colors = [["#B11", "#F22"], ["#DB0", "#FF0"]];
var frame = 0;    // counts frames

function drawCircles(angle, rotY) {  // rotZ rotates around Y axis (in and out of screen)
var i = 0;
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0";
const step = (2 * Math.PI) / numCircles;
const circles = [];

// The transform for y rotation
const dx = Math.cos(rotY);  
const dy = Math.sin(rotY);

// get 3D location of each circle
while (i < numCircles) {
     const x = ringRadius * Math.cos(angle + i * step);
     const y = ringRadius * Math.sin(angle + i * step);         
     circles.push({x: x * dx, y, z: x * dy, colIdx: i % 2});
     i++;
}  

// sort circles from back to front
circles.sort((a, b) => b.z - a.z);

// center on canvas
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1, ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2);

// draw 3D circles with perspective
for (const c of circles) {
     const col = colors[c.colIdx];
     // Calculate perspective scale. The further from the front the
     // smaller the perspective scale 
     const p = (perspectiveRange - c.z) / perspectiveRange;

     // Scale radius, x, y pos and line with by perspective scale
     const r = Math.abs(p * circleRadius);
     const x = p * c.x;
     const y = p * c.y;
     ctx.lineWidth = 1.5 * p;

     // shaded color
     ctx.fillStyle = col[0];
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.stroke();

     // highlight color
     ctx.fillStyle = col[1];
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(x - r * 0.1, y - r * 0.1, r * 0.8, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
     ctx.fill();

     ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFA";
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(x - r * 0.3, y - r * 0.3, r * 0.3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
     ctx.fill();


}

// reset canvas transform
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0, 0);
}


requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);  // rAF to start animation

function renderLoop() {  // rAF callback
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

time = frame++ * (1000 / 60);   // Assumes 60 fps
const ang = ((time * Math.PI * 2) / 1000) * rate
drawCircles(ang, ang / 2);

requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);  // request next frame
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "canvas" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
```

Comment: Its very helpful, also I want to rotate it at its axis I mean z-axis, how it is possible?

Comment: Hello please help how will I rotate this canvas like 3D (Z- axis) also.

Comment: @SaketKumar The canvas context `CanvasRenderingContext2D` as the name implies is not designed to render 3D. That does not mean it can not be done. See update in answer for more.